# How to optimize C non-blocking accept() socket connection

Tags: c, sockets

I have an app (server) that uses accept() to receive TCP socket connections from mobile phones (clients). It seems to work, but when I run my app in Apple Instruments I can see this app uses about 100% CPU  and the main reason 95% of it accounts for call to non-blocking accept(). I think I have added this non-blocking accept() method call in order to be able to stop server in any time by clicking GUI button "Stop Server". By this solution I can each time check whether I have a flag shouldShutDown equal to true and then I am closing the server()

[image]

Here is the code of server loop:

```
/**
 * Function is looping infinitely and waiting
 * for new incoming connections.
 * It handles each connection on thread pool's worker thread
 */
result_t thread_pool_stream_server_loop(server_info_t *server_info, connection_handler_t conn_handler) {

    sock_fd_t cs_fd, ps_fd;
    thread_pool_t *thread_pool;

    // get passive server socket
    ps_fd = server_info_sock(server_info);

    // initialize thread pool and set its size
    thread_pool_init(&thread_pool, 5, 10, 3000 /* [ms] */);

    while(1) {

        if(server_info_should_shut_down(server_info)) {
            thread_pool_shutdown(thread_pool);
            return CLOSED;
        }
        if(server_info_force_shut_down(server_info)) {
            thread_pool_shutdown(thread_pool);
            return FORCE_CLOSED;
        }

        // check to accept new connections on the main thread...
        cs_fd = accept_new_connection(ps_fd);

        if(cs_fd == FAILURE) {
            fprintf(stderr, "accept_new_connection: failed!\n");
            server_info_connection_error_event(server_info, cs_fd, CONN_ERROR_ACCEPT, "accept_new_connection: failed!");
            break;
        } else if(cs_fd == CONTINUE) {
            continue;
        }

        // publish client connected event
        server_info_client_connected_event(server_info, cs_fd);

        // revert connection socket to non-blocking
        int opts = fcntl(cs_fd, F_GETFL);
        opts = opts & (~O_NONBLOCK);
        fcntl(cs_fd, F_SETFL, opts);

        // handle new connection by thread pool's worker thread
        conn_thread_runner_attr_t *connection_thread_runner_attr;
        conn_thread_runner_attr_init(&connection_thread_runner_attr);
        conn_thread_runner_attr_fill(connection_thread_runner_attr, conn_handler, server_info, cs_fd, NULL, NULL);

        thread_pool_run(thread_pool, (runner_t) connection_thread_runner, (runner_attr_t) connection_thread_runner_attr, NULL);

        // adjust thread pool actual size to number of added connection handling tasks
        thread_pool_adjust_size(thread_pool);
    }

    thread_pool_force_free(thread_pool);
    return FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/5r143L6.png

Comment: "*By this solution I can each time check whether I have a flag shouldShutDown equal to true and then I am closing the server()*" - the code you're talking about isn't even in the picture. What do you expect us to do with this (lack of) information?

Comment: I have edited question and added code of this server loop

Comment: Use a blocking call.  Shut down the server by connecting to it over localhost and sending it a shutdown command in whatever protocol you are using.  No flag needed, no non-blocking loop required, no select/poll/epoll required, no CPU waste, no memory-bandwidth waste.

Comment: @MartinJames So as I understand should implement it this way: "Stop" button > then event handler starts new local client subprogram > it is connecting  to my main server > Sends some message like STOP. And then server has always blocking accept(). After someone connects it check whether it is real mobile phone client or my shutdown client. If it is shutdown then server is self shutting down. I think this is interesting approach and I will give it try! Please give write this in answer I accept it as good solution to my problem

Comment: @MichałZiobro thanks - have it as a freebie.   I've suggested it before on other Q's, so it would be a dupe if I posted an actual answer here, I don't need the rep and I would get hammered by my assocaites on SOCVR as a cucumber:)

Comment: Oh - on some server designs, you may need a stop flag as well as some STOP message:)  The localhost connect is then just there to persuade the accept() to return and no actual STOP message is needed:).

Answer (score 0):

The code is busy waiting, for `accept()` to return something different then `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK`, so what else then burning CPU cycles do you expect?

You could fix this by calling `select()`, with 10ms time-out, before calling `accept()`.